# Remove all duplicates from two given int arrays (no list)

Tags: java, arrays

I'm stuck at a task. Maybe someone can help me? I'm given two integer arrays of unknown length like Array 1 = {1, 4, 7, 3} and Array 2 = {1, 7}. I have to return a third Array containing only the integers which are only in one of the arrays. So in this case, Array 3 would be {4, 3}. I've tried something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  int [] range = {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
  int [] excludedValues = {1, 4, 6};
  int [] exclusionRange = new int [range.length - excludedValues.length + 1];

  for (int i = 0; i < range.length ; i++) {
      if (range[i] != Arrays.binarySearch(excludedValues, range[i])) {
          exclusionRange[i] = range[i];
      }
  }

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(exclusionRange)); // Should return {2, 3, 5, 7}
}
```

But it (obviously) doesn't work at all.

Here you can see a detailed description of the content which should be returned:

[image]

Thanks for your help in advance :)

Comment: You mean - no duplicates right ??

Comment: What exactly are your constraints? You can only use arrays, but you are not allowed to use any other collections, correct?

Answer (score 1):

I would simply use the built in Java functions of Lists.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int[] range = { 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
    int[] excludedValues = { 1, 4, 6 };
    
    List<Integer> list = Arrays.stream(range).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
    List<Integer> listE = Arrays.stream(excludedValues).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
    list.removeAll(listE);

    int[] exclusionRange = new int[list.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
        exclusionRange[i] = (int) list.get(i);

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(exclusionRange));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the picture you linked, i believe you want something like this

```java
import java.util.Arrays;

public class MyClass {
    public static int[] createRangeWithExclusions(int rangeStartInclusive,int rangeEndInclusive,int[] excludedValues){
       int sz = rangeEndInclusive - rangeStartInclusive  + 1;
       
       for(int exclude : excludedValues){
            if(exclude >= rangeStartInclusive && exclude <= rangeEndInclusive){
                sz--;
            }
        }
       
       
       int []ret = new int[sz];
       
       int idx = 0;
       for(int i = rangeStartInclusive; i <= rangeEndInclusive; i++){
           boolean include = true;
           for(int exclude : excludedValues){
               if(i == exclude){
                   include = false;
                   break;
               }
           }
           
           if(include){
               ret[idx] = i;
               idx++;
           }
       }
       
       return ret;
    }
    
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      int[] exlusions = {1,4,6};
      int [] resp = createRangeWithExclusions(2, 7, exlusions);

      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(resp));
    }
}
```

Comment: Simple and doesn't use anything "fancy". It could break if there are duplicate values in the exclusion array.

Answer (score 0):

If the ask is to filter common values from the given arrays, you can use [Apache Commons Collections library](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-collections4/4.4) to solve this issue, which gives a lot of utility functions.
For our use-case, you can use the `disjunction` function.

```
List<Integer> list1 = Arrays.asList(1, 3, 4, 7);
List<Integer> list2 = Arrays.asList(1, 7, 2);

System.out.println(CollectionUtils.disjunction(list1, list2)); //order does not matter here
```

Output

```
[2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
public static int[] findExclusionRange(int[] range, int[] excludedValues) {
    Set<Integer> unique = Arrays.stream(excludedValues)
                                .boxed()
                                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
    return Arrays.stream(range)
                 .boxed()
                 .filter(v -> !unique.contains(v))
                 .distinct()
                 .mapToInt(i -> i)
                 .toArray();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a variation of Henrique Possatto's answer, using a `List<Integer>` to accumulate the valid values:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int [] excludedValues = {-1, 1, 2, 3};
    int[] range = createRangeWithExclusions(-1, 3, excludedValues);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(range));
  }      

  public static int[] createRangeWithExclusions(int rangeStartInclusive, int rangeEndInclusive, int[] excludedValues) {
    // unknown number of values in resulting set, use a List and accumulate valid values
    List<Integer> lstRange = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    // iterate over the inclusive range values
    for(int i=rangeStartInclusive; i<=rangeEndInclusive; i++) {
      // examples include an array with non-sorted exclusion values, so we can't use a binary search
      // exclude values from the exclusion set
      boolean exclude = false;
      for(int x : excludedValues) {
        if (i == x) {
          exclude = true;
          break;
        }
      }    
      if (!exclude) {
        lstRange.add(i);
      }
    }

    // convert our List<Integer> to int[] and return it
    int index=0;
    int[] returnArray = new int[lstRange.size()];
    for(Integer i : lstRange) {
      returnArray[index++] = i;
    }
    return returnArray;
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

In JS we can solve the problem like this.

```
const fun = () => {
  let range = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
  let excludedValues = [1, 4, 6];
  let combineArr = [...range, ...excludeValues];
  let tempObj = {}
  for (let i =0;i<combineArr.length;i++) {
      if (tempObj[combineArr[i]]) {
         delete tempObj[combineArr[i]]
      } else {
         tempObj[combineArr[i]] = 1
      }
  }
  return Object.keys(tempObj)

  // System.out.println(Arrays.toString(exclusionRange));
}
```

Comment: Why post a JavaScript solution if this is clearly a Java question?